# Amazon AWS, Static IP ... instance now not booting

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services

I set up a web server using AWS with a few websites. As I had multiple websites, I set up the network card to have multiple static internal IPs (10.* range). At the time I did this, everything seemed to work. I got temporarily knocked out of my RDP session but once I reconnected I was able to bind each website to a new static IP and my websites worked.

I stopped my instance and came into the office today and now it seems the instance boots but fails the second initialisation test and I'm now unable to ping/remote/browse it. When I view the server log, it tells me ("2013/02/25 01:44:48Z: Waiting for meta-data accessibility...")

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to get it into a state where I can RDP into it (I hadn't taken a snapshot) ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a static IP-address assigned to a network adapter.
Create a new network interface and attach it to the instance.
You should be able to RDP into it.

More here ["Waiting for the metadata service"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/common-messages.html#metadata-unavailable).

Answer (score 0):

Stop the instance, associate the EBS volume with another Windows server, mount it, then figure out what is keeping the instance from booting. If possible, fix the problem, then re-associate the volume with the original instance, then start it back up.